# Integrating Subgit with GitLabs hosted git repository

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, subgit

I would like to use subgit to synchronize an SVN repo that I host, with a GitLab repository that I manage, but it is hosted on the gitlab server.

All the instructions that I see assume that gitlab is hosted on your own server, NOT using the gitlab service where they host the git reps for you.

thanks.

myles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SubGit requires filesystem-level access to the Git repository, so this is not possible.

What is possible is to create an intermediate Git repository, which you would host, synchronize it with SVN and keep the intermediate repository in sync with the repository on GitLab. Probably there're some automated tools for that, I don't know, but manual process is described in this [article](https://subgit.com/github.html#10) (with GitHub instead of GitLab, but the principle is the same).